# Reading data chunk by chunk - node.js at real time?

Tags: node.js, file, file-io

I am working on web analytics. For reporting the traffic and user information, I want to `read the flat file at real-time`, Flat file consist of user information in [extended log format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Log_Format).

**Requirement**

```
Reading the flat files at real-time which means, reading the particular chunk of data from the file and listening to the file for update if it is updated (new line or data added in the file) read the updated data and serve it for reporting.
```

**similar**

This technique is similar to [tail -f](http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/tail.php) in unix system.

**known**

[File reading](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) in node.js

Any techniques similar to this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

there is a [tail module](https://npmjs.org/package/tail) out there which is internally using [fs.watchFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) and [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

on startup you just "throw away" every line you do not need. all in all probably the easiest way to go...